# How to get an element based on raw_ptr from an unordered_set keyed on shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++14, shared-ptr, unordered-set

I am wondering if there is anyway for me to retrieve an element based on its raw pointer from an `unordered_set` keyed on `shared_ptr`.

```
unordered_set< shared_ptr<MyObj> > sets;
auto myobj = make_shared<MyObj>();
sets.insert(myobj);

// Find the element myobj
sets.find(myobj);

// How to find the element based on the underlying raw pointer?
sets.find(my.obj.get()); <---- apparently this gives compile error

// This method works but it will double free myobj though (not correct)
sets.find(shared_ptr<MyObj>(my.obj.get()));
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can declare `MyObj` as:

```
class MyObj : public std::enable_shared_from_this<MyObj>
{
     ....
}
```

This adds a method returning a shared pointer for a given object instance.

```
MyObj * rawptr = myobj.get();
sets.find(rawptr->shared_from_this());
```

Note that prior to calling `shared_from_this()` on an object, there must be a `std::shared_ptr` that owns it.

Answer (score 3):

To find what you are looking for using only the underlying raw pointer can be done by using std::set with heterogeneous lookup.

The caveat here is that you would have to use a set instead of an unordered_set. If you truly need the unordered (which I find is rare) then go with the shared_from_this() solution from alexm. Otherwise the heterogeneous lookup is a fairly elegant and flexible approach.

--

With heterogeneous lookup you just need to define a special comparitor that the set will use for its ordering function.

The following should do the trick:

```
struct Raw_comp{
  using is_transparent = std::true_type;
  bool operator()(const shared_ptr<MyObj>& lhs, const shared_ptr<MyObj>& rhs) const{
   return lhs < rhs;
}
  bool operator()(shared_ptr<MyObj>& lhs, MyObj* rhs) const{
   return std::less<MyObj>()(lhs.get(), rhs);
}
  bool operator()(const MyObj* lhs, const shared_ptr<MyObj>& rhs) const{
   return std::less<MyObj>()(lhs, rhs.get());
}
};
```

and then declare the set:

```
set< shared_ptr<myObj>, Raw_cmp> sets;
```

[Here is more information on heterogeneous lookup if you are interested](http://umich.edu/~eecs381/handouts/HeteroLookup.pdf)

Comment: 1) Given`MyObj *p1, *p2;`, `p1 < p2` is not well defined, but `std::less<MyObj*>{}(p1, p2)` is. 2) Passing `shared_ptr`s around by value when you don't want ownership is wrong; `shared_ptr const&` is totally valid and useful here. 3) Your first `operator()` is not using `.get()` as it should. 4) All `operator()` overloads should be `const`.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks for calling me out on my sloppy code.

I don't necessarily agree that #2 was wrong, but it does show the wrong intent and you are right that const& is the better choice.

As for #3, the < operator is valid for two shared_ptrs so that is okay.